# How to rigorously show that the sum of two subspaces is or isn't in the original subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am studying for an upcoming linear algebra exam and I don't understand how you can mathematically show that the sum of two subspaces *is* in the subspace or *is not* in the subspace.

Here is an example problem. Determine if W is a subspace of $R^3$
$$
        W = \begin{bmatrix} 
        x_1 \\
        x_2 \\
        x_1 x_2\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I understand that you want to add two vectors to test if W is a subspace of $R^3$ (and also test by multiplying by a constant, and test if the zero vector exists). So I did this:
$$
        j = \begin{bmatrix} 
        a \\
        b \\
        ab \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$ $$
        k = \begin{bmatrix} 
        c \\
        d \\
        cd \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$ $$
        j + k = \begin{bmatrix} 
        a + c \\
        b + d \\
        ab + cd \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I don't see how this helps me determine that j + k is not in W (which is the answer according to my textbook).

Comment: You are not considering the sum of two subspaces, you are considering the sum of two vectors. There's an important difference here.

Comment: But both of the vectors must be in the the "subspace", correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $j + k$ is in the subspace you are investigating, it must be of the form:
$\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_1x_2
\end{array}
\right]$

In this case, $x_1 = a +c$ and $x_2 = b + d$. What is $x_1x_2$?

Comment: (a + c)(b + d) = ab + ad + cb + cd. Ok that makes sense. So I apply the condition proposed to result of j + k. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It is perhaps easier to show that if the vector   $v$ is in $W$, and $c$ is a constant, then $cv$ is not necessarily in $W$. Take $x_1=x_2=1$ and $c=2$.